# How to award a higher bounty?

Tags: support

I had a 50 point bounty for this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31786/how-to-create-a-union-of-two-views) but it come up with no real solutions. I would like to start a 200 point bounty now, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each question can have only an open bounty at time. Once the grace period of the actual bounty is done, you can offer another bounty.

The "one bounty at time" limit is valid for every user. I cannot add a bounty to that question too.

[image: screenshot]

As it would be the second bounty you offer for that question, the minimum reputation you can offer is not 50 anymore, but 100.

You can also offer a maximum of three bounties for different questions that are open at the same time; once you reach that limit, you cannot offer more bounties, until one of them is  closed.

Comment: Now that the grace period is over, should I be able to open a bounty on that? Or add/increase to one that @MotoTribe re-offers?

Comment: You can, once the bounty banner is removed, and the "start a bounty" link re-appears. You cannot increase the existing bounty, in the same way you cannot alter the bounty you offered, once you set it.